# Unable to create the selected preference page. An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (597)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin, spring-tool-suite

While building the work space i am constantly getting this error in preferences under maven section.

I tried installing the maven plugins, rebuilding the work space ,cleaning the project etc but i cant resolve the issue.Tried editing the maven certificate and settings file.

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (597).

I hope to find some info so that i can fix this issue and build my project.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlbQn.png)

Comment: maybe these is a more comprehensive error message showing up in the Error Log view for this? Might reveal more details. Also did you try to restart your IDE with the "-clean" option via the command line once? Might also make a difference.

Comment: I did do that.I think the error us due to missing plugins or unsynchronized versions of the same.

Comment: You could try a clean install of the latest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution with a fresh workspace as well as your existing workspace, maybe that reveals more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help martin. I resolved the problem by updating the plugins and installing plugins and maven tools.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [reinstalling Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to resolve this issue.